# How to test a Rails engine that depends on its hosting application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a rails application, and I'm trying to split the code into several engines.

The main application Holds one main controller - `Api::ApplicationController`, and all the controllers in the engines inherit from that controller, for example:

```
Api::Products::ProductsController < Api::ApplicationController
```

I use RSpec for testing.

When I run the application everything works just perfect, but when I try to run the engine's Rspecs, I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant Api::ApplicationController
```

As you understand the engine cannot work separately from the application, so I tried to stub `Api::ApplicationController` inside the spec (products_controller_spec.rb), but it fails before it even starts to run the spec.

I thought maybe I should Implement it in a different way, and inject ApplicationController functionality somewhere instead of inherit from it, but I don't know where.

Another thing I considered, is to inject the engine's specs into the hosting application and run it from there, but it doesn't seem to work, and it is not possible to debug the specs that way.

How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

Rails Engines create small dummy applications for testing purposes. You need to create a minimal application that has the features you need to test your application, and it will use this to run it's specs.

See here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#testing-an-engine

A better solution for this case I think is to put shared application code that all the engines share as modules in a shared gem that all your engines can include.